# Javascript constructor - Use an object?

Tags: javascript, constructor

I'm trying to create a new object by using an already made object. This is what I am trying to achieve:

```
var obj = {"Name" : "Patrick", "Age": 25, "Country": "US"};
document.writeln(JSON.stringify(obj) + "<br />");

function Person(name, age, country) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.country = country;
}

document.writeln(JSON.stringify(new Person(obj)));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dotjz9tb/

As you can see, I am trying to create a new person called Patrick, aged 25, who happens to live in the US. My `Person` constructor takes a name, an age, and a country as parameters. However, my object has already been created from a previous function, so I would like to do `new Person(obj)` and it would create a new object based on `obj`'s parameters.

I know I can do `new Person(obj.name, obj.age, obj.country)` but I would rather pass the constructor an object instead, while still being able to do `new Person("Jack", 52, "UK")`.

Is such thing possible? Right now this is how it's really being created:

```
new Person(obj, undefined, undefined);
//or
{
    "name": {
        "Name":" Patrick","
         Age":25,
        "Country":"US"
    }
}
```

Meaning that `age` and `country` is set to nothing, while `name` is set to my object.

Comment: If constructor is `function Person(obj) {
    this.name = obj.Name;
    this.age = obj.Age;
    this.country = obj.Country;
}`

Comment: @Rayon Then I would have to create a new constructor, which takes an object as well, right?

Comment: Or conditions inside it...Something like `arguments.length` ?

Comment: @Rayon How would such constructor look? One that takes both an object and 3 parameters.

Comment: you may abuse of the "...arguments" format: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments , like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ghazkk1k/

Comment: @briosheje Oh wow I never knew that was possible. Interesting. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @Snorlax: I'm pretty sure that's the closest you can get, but I personally dislike it because I pretend to say that it's quite hard to mantain, forcing other programmers (if there are others) to just follow a rule (I would say providing an object with the needed parameters) is way better than forcing yourself to provide multiple solutions, in any case that should be the closest to your case and (should) be supported in all major browsers, mobile ones included as far as I can tell :) (even IE mobile supports it!..)

Comment: @briosheje Yeah you are completely right. I'll probably just go with the way, that checks if the first argument is an object, then I will set the appropriate variables like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have plenty of options here.

For example you could make your `Person` polymorphic on arguments it takes.

```
function Person(name, age, country) {
   if(arguments.length === 1 && typeof name === 'object') {
      var data = arguments[0];
      name = data.name; //etc
   } 
   //the rest of ctor code goes here
}
```

Or **BETTER** use factory function and keep your constructor code as simple is possible

```
function copyPerson(obj) {
   return new Person(obj.name, obj.age, obj.country);
}

//or even
Person.copy = function(obj) {
   return new this(obj.name, obj.age, obj.country)
}
```

Comment: Creating a new function is kind of "meh". I'd rather stick with one constructor.

Comment: Well, it's up to you. But making your constructor code too complex is an antipattern. Factory functions is way more maintainable.

Comment: I completely agree, however, I would just like to do `new Person()` and parse it either an object or some parameters.

Comment: @Snorlax Then I'd recommend you to make your constructor take an object `function Person(data)` and move the other case to a separate functon.

Comment: I'm confused as to why you would put the BETTER answer last, or even include a WORSE answer.

Comment: @torazaburo To answer ORIGINAL question. :)

Answer (score 1):

In general it's better to avoid polymorphic interfaces. They end up being hard to maintain and document and remember.

In this case, I'd change the signature of the constructor to take an object, so

```
function Person(data) {
  Object.assign(this, data);
}
```

Now you can call it as

```
var patrick = new Person({name: 'Patrick', age: 25, country: 'US'});
var patrick2 = new Person(patrick);
```

Comment: Yeah this would be the best way to do it. Absolutely. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you could do to support both the input formats:

```
   function Person(name, age, country) {
        var obj;
        if(typeof(name) === 'object'){
          obj = name;
          name = obj.name;
          age = obj.age;
          country = obj.country;
        }
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.country = country;
    }
```

Comment: So far this looks like the best option for me. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, it's not. It's best to avoid this kind of polymorphism. Instead, have a `copy` method on the class, as one answer suggested, or a `clone` method on the instances (in the prototype).

Comment: Yup I completely agree, however, I don't want to make it "more complex" than it needs to be.

Comment: Does anyone know if it's possible to, in this case, just `name` instead of `this.name`?

Answer (score 0):

```
var Person = function(nameOrObj, age, country) {
  if (typeof nameOrObj === 'object') {
    this.name = nameOrObj.name
    this.age = nameOrObj.age
    this.country = nameOrObj.country
  } else {
    this.name = nameOrObj
    this.age = age
    this.country = country
  }
}
```